# Wordpress thumbnails on home page not showing up

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm hosting my wordpress site on `Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03`. Whenever I upload any custom theme to my website, the thumbnails for the posts fail to show up on [my home page](http://adeln.com/).

When I searched the answers community someone advised me to install `php-gd`, and I did so. It worked fine and thumbnails appeared on my home page. I don't know know why, after two days again the same problem started.

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem. I'm not a professional developer or programmer. So, kindly be detailed. Please tell me what to do and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you have checked gd extension enable or not in php.ini ;extension=php_gd2.dll if sami colone is exiest then remove sami colone

and read

```
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpgd/About-thumbnail.html

http://davidwalsh.name/create-image-thumbnail-php
```

Read below url:-

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
```

or

try this:-

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?> 

<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 1)); ?> 
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <h1><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h1>
            <?php echo $page->post_content; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Thumbnail Sizes

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($id);                  // without parameter -> Thumbnail

get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'thumbnail');     // Thumbnail
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'medium');        // Medium resolution
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'large');         // Large resolution
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'full');          // Original resolution

get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(100,100) ); // Other resolutions
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr.Abid. But these are fine with the theme. I've set the featured images for every post with the "use as featured image" option. As I said earlier that after installing php-gd the thumbnails worked fine for a few days. But now they are again not showing up. The situation now is just like that of when I didn't install php-gd. Sometimes it even says that "error establishing database connection". When I restart the server, the error this database error subsides for a small time but the thumbnail issue doesn't solve at all.

Comment: you have checked gd extension enable or not in php.ini ;extension=php_gd2.dll if sami colone is exiest then remove sami colone

Comment: There is no such line in php.ini. The only line present under [GD] is:
;gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 0

Comment: As you can observe by visiting my website that the thumbnail image url is generated like this.
http://adeln.com/wp-content/themes/cadabrapress/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://adeln.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/4072028-4x3-700x525_2.jpg&w=75&h=75&zc=1

and the image is fine but the thumbnail appears broken